# I was given an equivalence in $L:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^2$, but I am becoming unsure if it is true

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I was given this equivalence, one direction seems trivial, while the other doesn't seem to be true.

For $L:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^2$, $L\not\equiv0$, take that there is some $v\in\mathbb{R}^2\backslash\{0\}$ for which $L(v)=0$. There is no nonzero eigenvalue for $L$.

The supposedly equivalent statements are

1. $Lw\not\in\text{span}\{w\}$ for each $w\in\mathbb{R}^2\backslash\text{span}\{v\}$
2. $Lw\in\text{span}\{v\}\backslash\{0\}$ for every $w\in\mathbb{R}^2\backslash\text{span}\{v\}$

$2\implies1$ is trivial.

If $Lw\in\text{span}\{v\}\backslash\{0\}$, then $Lw=\lambda_1v$ for some $\lambda_1\in F\backslash\{0\}$. The span of any $w$ can be represented by the set $\lambda_2w$ for some $\lambda_2\in F$ and as $w\in\mathbb{R}^2\backslash\text{span}\{v\}$, there are no $\lambda_1,\lambda_2$ s.t. $\lambda_1v=\lambda_2w$. Thus, $Lw\not\in\text{span}\{w\}$.

$1\implies2$ seems much more tricky.

If I am correct, I would have to assert that for every $w\in\mathbb{R}^2\backslash\text{span}\{v\}$, that $L$ maps $w$ to the span of $v\backslash\{0\}$. What I don't see is why $L$ could not map any $w$ to any other $w$. This doesn't seem to be necessitated by any of the initial conditions.

Ultimately, $2\implies 1$ is simple because it asserts that if $Lw$ is in a span, it is not in another, distinct, span. $1\implies 2$, on the other hand, would assert that if $Lw$ is not in a span then it must be in another specific span.

I have been drawing a plane with $v$ and a collection of $w$ and tried to imagine a reason why every $w$ would have to map to $\text{span}\{v\}\backslash\{0\}$ under $L$ but I can't come up with an intuitive/visual explanation either. At this point I have started to try to find a counterexample to show that 1 does not imply 2, but I am having difficulty constructing such a specific transformation. Thank you!

Comment: The hypothesis that $L(v) = 0 = 0 \cdot v$ is in contradiction with the one that there is no eigenvalue/eigenvector.

Comment: Good point, I will edit it to reflect that there are no nonzero eigenvalues

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's assume that 1 holds. Let $w$ be a vector which is not in the span of $v$. Then $(v, w)$ forms a basis of $\mathbb{R}^2$. We can thus write $Lw = \alpha \cdot v + \beta \cdot w$ for some scalars $\alpha, \beta \in \mathbb{R}$. We have that:
$$L(L(w)) = \alpha \cdot \underbrace{L(v)}_{= \, 0} + \beta \cdot L(w) = \beta \cdot L(w).$$
Given our assumption that $L$ has no nonzero eigenvalue, we must either have $\beta = 0$ or $L(w) = 0$. But if $Lw$ were equal to zero, it would be in the span of $w$, which contradicts hypothesis 1. Therefore, we must have that $\beta = 0$ and thus that $L(w) = \alpha \cdot v$ is in the span of $v$. Moreover we must have $\alpha = 0$, as other $L(v) = L(w) = 0$ implies that $L$ is identically zero (which contradicts one of the hypotheses).

---

A different way of viewing this is the following. The linear map $L$ can be triangularized over $\mathbb{C}$. Since $v$ is an eigenvector already, we can assume that it is the first vector of the basis in which $L$ is triangularized, so that the matrix of $L$ looks like:

$$\begin{pmatrix} 0 & \alpha \\ 0 & \beta \end{pmatrix}$$

But if $\beta \neq 0$, it would be an eigenvalue of $L$ (because the characteristic polynomial would be $X(X-\beta)$, which is false by hypothesis. Now the matrix looks like $\left( \begin{smallmatrix} 0 & \alpha \\ 0 & 0 \end{smallmatrix} \right)$ and it's easy so see that for any vector not in the span of the first one, the image under $L$ is in the span of the second one.

Comment: Thank you! Both of those solutions make a lot of sense. No wonder I could not construct a counterexample.